Customize PieChartSectionData title with different styles
I have a pie chart visualisation, and I want to customize its sections. Specifically, I want fund.name to be in FontWeight.bold, and fund.amount.toStringAsFixed(2) to be in green. But I do not know how to do it, because title must be a String.
I tried for example to convert rich text to String, but it did not work.
I am using fl_charts: ^0.68.0
List<PieChartSectionData> _getSections(List<fund> allFunds) {
  return allFunds.map((fund) {
    return PieChartSectionData(
      color: fund.color,
      value: fund.amount,
      title: '${fund.name}\n ${fund.amount.toStringAsFixed(2)} €',
      titlePositionPercentageOffset: 2,
      badgeWidget: SvgPicture.asset(
        fund.svg,
        height: 26,
        color: fund.color,
      ),
      badgePositionPercentageOffset: 0.5
    );
  }).toList();
}

At the moment I have this :

But I want this :

